# EXTJS - Returning a form object

Tags: extjs

I'm developing a form using EXTJS 3.4 library. But I get some issues when I try to return a form object from a EXTJS Panel of the type form.

My configuration form is like bellow:

```
config = Ext.apply({            
    title: 'Fluxo de Reincidencia',
    id: 'formKMLRcd',
    name: 'formKMLRcd',
    border: true,
    bodyStyle: "padding: 10px",
    layout: "form",                     
    autoScroll: false,          
    items: [{
        xtype: "datefield",
        ref: "../extent",
        anchor: "100%",
        fieldLabel: 'Data Inicio',
        emptyText: 'informe a data de inicio',
        name: 'txtRcdDataInicio',
        id: 'txtRcdDataInicio',
        format:'d/m/Y',
        altFormats:'d/m/Y',
        allowBlank: false,
        validator: function(value){
            var date = this.parseDate(this.getValue());
            if (!date){
                return 'Informe uma data valida';
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is my problem, when I try to return the form from this expression I got a error:

```
var form = Ext.getCmp('formKMLRcd').getForm();
```

Any one knows how to return a form from my config object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error because you are using a panel and not a form panel. In your config, you are using a "form layout" in a panel. To get a form using the `getform` method you should be using a form panel.

```
config = Ext.apply({            
    title: 'Fluxo de Reincidencia',
    id: 'formKMLRcd',
    name: 'formKMLRcd',
    xtype: 'form'  // Makes sure that the panel is form panel and not ordinary panel
    ... // rest of the code
```

And now you should be able to get the underlaying form using the `getForm` method!